# Why were Job's sheep burned by Satan in Job 1:16?

Tags: job

Is there any reason why Job 1:16 where Job's sheep are burned is placed in the middle of two accounts where his other livestock was stolen.

> And the Sabeans fell upon them, and took them away; yea, they have slain the servants with the edge of the sword; and I only am escaped alone to tell thee.
>
> While he was yet speaking, there came also another, and said, The fire of God is fallen from heaven, and hath burned up the sheep, and the servants, and consumed them; and I only am escaped alone to tell thee.
>
> While he was yet speaking, there came also another, and said, The Chaldeans made out three bands, and fell upon the camels, and have carried them away, yea, and slain the servants with the edge of the sword; and I only am escaped alone to tell thee. Job 1:15-17

I understand that placing something in the middle is a means of emphasis. Is that the case here too and if so why?

Answer (score 2):

The four calamities that befell Job (Job 1:13-19) show some interesting patterns:

| Object | Satan's Instrument #1 | Verb 1 | Verb 2 | Verb 3 | Satan's Instrument #2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Oxen, donkeys and servants | Sabeans | נָפַל (naphal) = swept down | לָקַח (laqach) = took away | נָכָה (nakah) = killed | Edge of the sword |
| Sheep & servants | Fire of God | נָפַל (naphal) = swept down | בָּעַר (ba'ar) = burned | אָכַל (akal) = consumed | (same fire of God) |
| Camels & servants | Chaldeans | פָשַׁט (pashat) = raided | לָקַח (laqach) = took away | נָכָה (nakah) = killed | Edge of the sword |
| Sons and daughters | Great wind | נָגַע (naga) = struck | נָפַל (naphal) = swept down | מוּת (muth) = died | 4 corners of the house |

Note that there are several "almost" patterns here. More importantly, note the repetition of some of the verbs, especially, "swept down" (3 times), "took away" (twice), and "killed" (twice).  The final verb is "died" just to add finality to the process.

The four disasters are human, natural, human, natural, but all have a supernatural ring to them.  The effect on Job is two-fold - total loss and despair.

The mood created by the above progression is that of growing doom and hopelessness.

Answer (score 1):

"Tzon" צֹּאן (Sheep & Goats) allowed Job the Edomite to maintain Noachide sin-atonement methods through Burnt-Offerings, as stated in [Iyov 1:5] - "Iyov said, "Perhaps my sons have sinned and blasphemed Elohim in their hearts." So would [Iyov] do all the days." ( אָמַר אִיּוֹב אוּלַי חָטְאוּ בָנַ֔י וּבֵֽרְכוּ אֱלֹהִים בִּלְבָבָם כָּכָה יַֽעֲשֶׂה אִיּוֹב כָּל־הַיָּמִֽים )

Without צֹּאן (Sheep & Goats), the אֵשׁ אֱלֹהִים "Fire of Elohim" ensures Job's righteousness depends on his faith in YHVH by removing traditional options for sin-atonement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that how Job lost his properties (livestocks and the dependents) is not the key message, rather, he lost his properties all at the same moment is the key.

Note the sole survivor of each incidents came one after another, the context repeatedly wrote **"While he was still speaking, another messenger came and said"**. So before Job could take a relieve from the first blow, another blow add on, and four blows in a row without relieve. This was the plan Satan played, as he wanted to use the hardest strike on Job to prove his words correct, since he told the Lord

Job 1:11 (NIV)

> But now stretch out your hand and strike everything he has, and he will surely curse you to your face.